# Мы ставим точку, когда пишем по стихотворным строкам текст?

Tags: точка

Мы ставим точку, когда пишем по стихотворным строкам текст?

`Зарою я веник на даче.`

`Пусть, на фиг, растёт он в цене.`

А когда в тексте цитируем с помощью слеша?

`Зарою я веник на даче. / Пусть, на фиг, растёт он в цене.`

Comment: А _на фиг_ выделяется запятыми, что ли?